# Generated Runnable jar: Could not find the main class

Tags: java, eclipse

I've always used the Export -> Runnable jar option of Eclipse and it has worked perfectly, but today it seems that all the Runnable jars I create produce the following error **when I run them**: *(Edit: run them by double clicking the file.)*

`Java Virtual Machide Launcher`

`Could not find the main class: (class). Program will exit.`

I've tried everything for the past two hours, but it still doesn't work.

- I can still run jars that I have created in the past without a
  problem.
- The manifest file looks exactly the same as in those jars
  that work and all the `.class` files seem to be in place...
- I've tried exporting with `Package required libraries into generated jar` but the file still doesn't work. **It doesn't show the error though - double clicking the file does nothing.**

**Edit**: Running the jar file through the `cmd` works perfectly, but simply double clicking on it yields this error. (*Bragboy*)

**Edit 2:**
Contents of a manifest file from a jar that works: (Obviously they're the same, just wanted to avoid confusion.)

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   Class-Path: .
>   Main-Class: defender.DefenderComponent (+ two empty lines afterwards)

And contents of a manifest file from a jar that doesn't work: (When opening the file directly)

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   Class-Path: .
>   Main-Class: pixel.Entry (+ two empty lines afterwards)

Both main class files are confirmed to be at their respective locations.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly specify the main class ?

Comment: @Bragboy please explain.

Comment: check my answer. let me know if that solves it. if not, i would need to take a look at the generated manifest file.

Comment: Could you please post the contents of MANIFEST.MF? Also check which program is associated with .jar files in your OS. Did you use any settings / libraries that you didn't use in the jars that are working fine?

Comment: @Tobold edited them into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the only thing that fixed this was to switch from JRE 1.7 down to JRE 1.6.

Comment: i guess this is the best answer, coz i was working in my station with jre 1.7 and now switched with jre 1.6  ....... thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

While exporting the jar file, it is important to specify which is the main class. You can do this in the eclipse wizard. To get to this screen, you need to simply export as just a jar as opposed to Runnable jar.

[image]

One more option to find out the error, try to open a command prompt (in windows) or a terminal (in linux/mac) and give this command java -jar your_jar.jar . this will show a detailed error on what is happening.

Since your jar works properly when launched via command prompt, the definite culprit would be the default program opening for .jar extension in windows. To avoid this, you should probably have to right click on the jar and try open with a jar executable that is compatible with the java version that you ran the same from the command prompt.

Comment: Exporting a normal jar doesn't ask me to specify a main class, nor was I able to manually find such an option. Running the jar via the console however - WORKS PERFECTLY. What could it be that prevents me from opening the jar just by clicking on it..?

Comment: @Acidic: Updated the answer. checkout

Comment: I just realized that my older projects were JRE 1.6 while the ones that don't work are 1.7. Changing the new ones to 1.6 indeed fixes the problem, but why is this happening? I updated my Java just in case, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Acidic: I suggest you update the question with this new information.

Comment: Well, you're the only one that tried to help and I did solve my problem in-directly thanks to you, so I give you the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Acidic: you're welcome. happy to see that it helped solve your problem !

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit of a thread necro, but I was having the same problem. What finally worked for me was fixing my %JAVA_HOME% path in environment variables. Turns out it was still pointing to a 1.6 release, and that's why nothing since I installed 1.7 was running except through Eclipse where I had fixed all the references to point to the correct release.