# Java jar running

Tags: java, jar, double-click

Any idea why

```
java -jar jarname.jar
```

works, but double clicking the jar gives a

`"Could not find the main class:"`

error? Manifest is correctly placed and double clicking was working until recently, but all of a sudden it gives that error. I'm not sure what changes I made though.

EDIT:
The command I used to create the jar was (in cmd):

```
jar cfe jarname.jar files.Main *
```

Main is part of the package files.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875839/jar-file-keeps-giving-me-could-not-find-the-main-class-program-will-exit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629412/generated-runnable-jar-could-not-find-the-main-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been some weird compiler version problem. When I complied the class files using an older version of java, then compiled it into a .jar file, it was able to run.

Answer (score 1):

Add this entry in your manifest file:

```
Main-Class: com.abc.def.YourMainClass
```

Hope this'll help!

Comment: Did you made this jar using IDE?

Comment: Did you write fully qualified name of your `MainClass` in manifest file?

Comment: What do you mean by fully qualified?

Comment: The full class name, including the package name. Like if my main class is `HelloWorld.class` then i would write something like this: `com.xyz.HelloWorld`.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had a comparable problem. And it was caused by multiple JDK/JRE versions on my machine.
What is used by double-clicking differs from what is used by typing `jar` in a shell.

I think [JarFix](http://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html) could help. Or you lookup what is associated with double-click in the file-associations (reinstall java might also help)